# Can ignition coil over plug fail intermittently?

Tags: toyota, ignition-coil, sienna, coil-on-plug, p035x

I'm getting P0352 on my '08 Toyota Sienna. Even after the dash lights up, the vehicle runs perfectly smoothly with no indication of ongoing failure (e.g., idle smooth, acceleration normal).

If I clear the code everything will be fine, usually until I start the vehicle and then the code comes in after a few minutes of driving. Once it came in while idling at a stop light, and I did feel the engine miss I'm guessing a single fire, and the dash lit up right after.

Does this sound like a failing coil or an electrical connection? Of course I can replace the coil, but if it's an electrical connection somewhere upstream, then coil replacement didn't do me a whole lot of good.

Comment: P0352 refers to cylinder #2. If you want to test to see if the coil is the issue, even intermittently, change it out with another coil and see if the problem follows or if it stays on cyl #2. I don't think it'd be the coil (though it might be) considering the code itself says there's a problem with the ignition system pre- (ECU) or post-coil (spark plug), but not necessarily the coil itself.

Comment: Sorry, I did re-edit and add to the comment.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 My BlueDriver app reports the code as "Ignition Coil "B" Primary Control Circuit Open" and that the top reported fix is "REPLACED DIRECT IGNITION COIL". But I will swap it out and see what happens - fortunately this is one of the front three cylinders

Comment: Actually, my apologies ... I misread the code a little bit. You are correct as the code is stating there's a problem with the windings, either the primary windings or the secondary windings. The windings are internal to the coil itself. Still, exchanging the coil with another will tell you the true tale. If the problem persists and follows the coil, you have your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Yes.

Swap coil 2 out with coil 4 to verify the coil is faulty.

Test drive until code P0354 comes in.

Replace the faulty coil.